# Alpine hangs when trying to mount NFS

Tags: mount, nfs, alpine-linux

I set up my mount using ext4 filesytem and mount it with `/etc/fstab`

```
uuid=<uuid> /mnt/external ext4 rw,realtime 0 2
```

I set up nfs by installing the apk

```bsh
apk add nfs-utils
```

I set up my exports file `/etc/exports`

```
/mnt/external *(rw,no_subtree_checks,no_root_squash,async)
```

I add nfs to boot and start the service

```
rc-update add nfs
rc-service nfs start
```

I attempt to mount the folder to a local temp folder

```
mkdir ~/tmp
mount -t nfs -o vers=4 192.168.0.120:/mnt/external ~/tmp
```

The command doesn't exit. The command hangs until I manually interrupt using `ctrl` + `c`

My kernel version is `5.10.43-0-lts`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check that your server is accessible. I faced with the same symptoms, as it turned out, the connection was blocked by the firewall. After I added an allow rule for port `2049`, it worked.